# TPM worked on windows iot-core buld 10.0.16299 RPi-3 but not on build 10.0.17763

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-edge

Our RPi TPM Module LetsTrust TPM V2 chip SLB 9670 TPM 2.0 FW7.40 worked fine as "Discrete SPI TIS Class TPM on SPI0CS1" on iot-core 10.0.16299 RPi3.

Upgrade to newest preview iot-core 10.0.17763 (to support IoT-Edge) now produces following error when TPM-Configuration is activated in the iot-core Device Portal on the device.

0x800c0005: Invalid manifest: missing Title attribute.

Any ideas where to start here?

**EDIT:** Same applies for default TPMs in iot-core version 10.0.17* See comment.

Comment: The module is compatible with Windows 10 IoT (on Pi 2 / 3).But it seems to be shipped with firmware versions >= 7.63 for TPM 2.0. Have you tried to upgrade the firmware for Windows IoT Core Build 17763?

Comment: Did you mean you would reinstall the Windows IoT Core?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Looking into that and will reinstall iot-core since I get the same error now after I remove the TPM-module from the RPi and reboot. Error text from iot-core could be better

Comment: If the problem is fixed after reinstall the iot core,please let me know.

Comment: You need to take a look: looks like all releases that begin with 17 have this problem and it has nothing to do with the TPM-module. I re-installed everything including the iot-core sdk, iot-core dashboard and even swapped the RPi3 HW. Same error on all 17* releases (e.g. Current OS Version: 10.0.17763.107)

Comment: I'm sorry that i don't have this Module to reproduce this issue.You can use feedback hub app to report this build issue.The Feedback Hub app lets you tell Microsoft about any problems you run in to while using Windows 10 and send suggestions to help us improve your Windows experience.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It also happens with the default TPM (software) module in edition 17*. I am now suspecting a firewall filter ... investigating. Any tip where to find this log data in iot-core app console?

Comment: You can try to use Event Tracing for Windows ([ETW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/eventtracing)) to trace the event log on Windows IoT Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this same problem and it ended up being that my Win 10 IoT machine had no internet access and I assume wasn’t able to install the Tpm tools as a result. Once I connected to the Internet the the option to install the Tpm tools showed up and I was able to provision my Azure connection string accordingly.

Comment: I'll accept this but the problem/solution was a bit different in our case. You see the new 17* version of iot-core enforces end-to-end TLS. Only new "ng" firewalls/gateways have the spyware to successfully imitate e2e-TLS. We got an NG firewall, and it worked again. The error message that we got was no help.